# PHP CURL - Problems storing and using cookies when scraping

Tags: php, html, cookies, curl, web-scraping

I've been trying to write a script that retrieves Google trends results for a given keyword. Please note im not trying to do anything malicious I just want to be able to automate this process and run it a few times every day.

After investigating the Google trends page I discovered that the information is available using the following URL:

http://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?hl=en-GB&q=keyword&cmpt=q&content=1

You can request that information mutliple times with no issues from a browser, but if you try with "privacy mode" after 4 or 5 requests the following is displayed:

> An error has been detected You have reached your quota limit. Please
>   try again later.

This makes me think that cookies are required. So I have written my script as follows:

```
$cookiefile = $siteurl . '/wp-content/plugins/' . basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/cookies.txt';


$url = 'http://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?hl=en-GB&q=keyword&cmpt=q&content=1'; 
$ch = curl_init();      

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);


$x='error';
while (trim($x) != ''  ){
     $html=curl_exec($ch);
     $x=curl_error($ch);
}

echo  "test cookiefile contents = ".file_get_contents($cookiefile)."<br />";
echo $html;
```

However I just can't get anything written to my cookies file. So I keep on getting the error message. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong with this?

Comment: I answered below. But google has a lot of tricks to not letting people scrape their data. Its common to return an error, when in reality they would be blocking you.

Comment: If  you use curl carefully google will never know if its human or curl unless there is captcha.

Comment: What's the value of `$siteurl`? This should be a filesystem path, not a url.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your cookie file should exist before you can use it with curl.
Try:

```
$h = fopen($cookiefile, "x+");
```